# How to extract impervious areas from Landsat data?

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, land-classification

I'm working with multi-temporal datasets from Landsat (Landsat 8 & Landsat 7 & Landsat 5) and I tried to extract impervious areas, more exactly urban areas, but I can't obtained results very close to reality (accuracy was approximately 80 % by using reference point in Google Earth). 
I used supervised  classification: SAM & Maximum Likelihood, then logical classification (between SAVI + MNDWI + NDBI) but I can't obtained very good results. I used bands: Red, Green, Blue, NIR, MIR, SWIR 2.
How I can extract urban areas from different Landsat image? What methods would you me recommend ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Can you edit your question to include which software suites you would like to use?

Answer (score 2):

Classifying urban areas from Landsat data is a common practice and usually yields accurate results.  To improve your accuracy I would reassess your training data.  As a rule-of-thumb: 1) the more samples the better, 2) samples should be distributed evenly throughout the scene.  There are numerous studies on just this topic:

1. [Extraction of urban built-up land features from Landsat
   imagery...](http://asprs.org/a/publications/pers/2007journal/december/2007_dec_1381-1391.pdf)
2. [An assessment of landsat MSS and TM data for urban and near-urban
   land-cover digital classification](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0034425787900538)
3. [Land cover classification and change analysis of the Twin Cities
   (Minnesota) Metropolitan Area by multitemporal Landsat remote
   sensing](http://www.abdn.ac.uk/geospatial/ers/PAPERS/classification.pdf)
4. [Urban classification using full spectral information of Landsat
   ETM+ imagery in Marion County, Indiana](http://isu.indstate.edu/~qweng/November%2005%20PERS.pdf)
5. [Use of impervious surface in urban land-use classification](http://isu.indstate.edu/~qweng/RSE06.pdf)